# How to achieve this simple screen with UIScrollView and AutoLayout

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

[image]

First of all, I understand the basic of using `UIScrollView` with `AutoLayout` by reading: https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html

What I want to achieve is:

- `UIScrollView` takes up the full screen height
- `UIButtons` are positioned like the above wireframe

I understand the `contentSize` of `UIScrollView` is determined by the position of the button at the bottom and its bottom space constraint to the `UIScrollView`, problem is I couldn't find a way to properly position the button at the bottom to make it work for 3.5" and 4" respectively

Comment: Are your buttons in fixed positions on the screen, with the scrollview scrolling behind them?

Comment: Hi David, the reason of using scrollview is to scroll up the whole screen when keyboard is presented (there are some UITextField on this screen as well). So, the buttons are supposed to scroll with the scrollview

Answer (score 1):

Put your `UIButton`s & `UIScrollView` in a parent `UIView`. Do not include *buttons* in *scrollview*, but instead put them in parent view. Arrage them as per your layout.

Now select the *button* & go to **Editor -> Pin** & click on **Height**. For *top buttons* pin **Top Space to Superview** & for *bottom buttons* pin **Bottom Space to Superview**.

For your *scrollview & parent view* pin **Top & Bottom Space** but **DO NOT** pin **height**, this will strech it to 100% height, while keeping button of same height & at their respective place.

Comment: hi, please see my reply to David. The buttons are supposed to be scrolled with the scrollview.